# How to monitor an advertisement?

Tags: ads, advertisement-server

Google Adwords lets you(a business owner), advertise with Google, your ads are served via google's partnered website! and you can actively monitor your ads!

but what if we want a company (lets call it company X) to advertise on our website, how can we serve company's X ads on our website and let company X monitor
their advertisements click-through rate and the number of impressions the ad is shown on our website?

Is there a 3rd party service we could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenX](http://www.openx.org/ad-server) (what used to be PhpAdsNew) might be a little on the heavy/complex side if you only have one other advertiser, but it's made for this.  You can mix Adwords in along with whatever other ad campaigns as you see fit, and clients are given an account to log in & check their numbers.

Comment: Can we restrict the advertiser to only view the ad campaign statistics? the advertiser can look after his own ad campaign, without any effort from us? (publisher?)

Comment: Been a while since I used it, but I don't think the advertiser has access to anything but stats.  If they do, it probably passes straight to the publisher for approval (e.g. uploading ad images & such).  It's free/open, worth checking out first-hand if only to compare against other packages.